# How do I enable Forced Overflow Mode in ActionBarSherlock 4.2.0?

Tags: java, android, xml

Okay, so Yes I am aware that The feature is removed in 4.2.0,  And it "shouldn't have been added in the first place", but Some still use it, and I use it with  HoloEverywhere, so How can I enable it? Where do I go? Is it in ABS' Configuration or java files? Please, I know how people feel about the feature, and I'm aware of people's feelings towards it, So please don't answer with "Look at so-and-so's comment here:" or "This was removed in 4.2.0 etc".  Again I'd like to enable Forced Overflow Mode (absForceOverflow) for all themes: Light, dark, mixed or custom? Please Help all answers are helpful, except for those I've already seen.

Comment: I'd say probably just roll back to a previous version of ABS.

Answer (score 0):

Since that feature was removed from the 4.2 code, it just isn't there to be quickly enabled. You have a couple of options --

1) Continue to use version 4.1 instead of 4.2 
2) Fork the code and merge 4.2 updates with 4.1 codebase contained forced overflow.  Someone else may have already done this or being working on because this feature seems to have a signifcant userbase, but I did not find it with a quick google search
3) Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875081/actionbarsherlock-forceoverflow-resource-not-found) for simulating the overflow button, which appears to have the advantage that it works on 4.0+ devices, unlike ABS.

Comment: I've been trying to merge the code... but where would I merge it? What pars of the code contain and manage the Fore Overflow feature?

Comment: Never mind.. I edited abs based off of the changes on Github and re added force overflow to 4.2.0.