# Menu button is not show in 3.0 OS

Tags: android, android-menu

I have created menu button which have two functions bookmark and home button. 
This is working well in all the android version without android 3.0

do here any ways ? so my menu button will be display also in android 3.0 with all the version.

my code:-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_bookmark:
            db.updateContact(new Contact(itemN,imageStatus));  
              return true;
        case R.id.home_page:
            Intent i = new Intent(imageTouchs.this, Comics.class);
            startActivity(i); 
              return true;
              default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }    

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
         return true;
    }
```

and my androidmanifest.xml :-

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
     android:title="Bookmark"
     android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"  />
<item android:id="@+id/home_page"
     android:title="Home" 
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"  />
</menu>
```

any menu is not display in action bar

Answer (score 1):

The "overflow' button will only show up when there isn't a physical menu button on the device.  This is the standard behavior for the ActionBar.

You can actually set the value of your AVD to specifically not have a menu button when you are configuring the image.

Here is a SO question addressing this same thing: [Action bar overflow not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905974/action-bar-overflow-not-displayed)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the `OverFlowMenu` icon, to the best of my knowledge, it cannot be achieved (**forced**) using the standard [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html).

If you must have an `OverFlowMenu` (**forced**), you will need to use the [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library. Go through a couple of my answers where I have a few  fairly detailed suggestions on how to achieve that:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13307583/450534
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13180285/450534

**NOTE:** As already mentioned in both my answers linked above, this is not recommended to ensure users get a seamless UI on their devices. And also, if you must absolutely force the `OverFlowMenu`, you will need to use an **older version of ABS**, which is again, not recommended.

Comment: thank you . i update my code . and any menu is not display in action bar using android 3.0